Tensorflow Data Arrangement and Model Selection/Type Question
Good Afternoon,
First off, I am very new to the machine learning world, so I am going to apologize in advance if I am not even asking the question correctly and while I did not find what I was looking for after searching it is possible I missed something already answered when the question was asked a different way.
I am looking into machine learning to help out with some analytics around some work my dad does on utility usage in real-estate, but I always find that I learn better when I am learning on data I am familiar with.  What I have is a large DB of stock data, calculated technical indicators, etc. and that is what I am practicing on (do not worry I have no delusions I am going to make any money with this it's just a familiar data set).
I have two use cases I am trying to work on as part of the learning process.

given a string of inputs predict if the stock will be up or down in x number of days.
Given a stock I know was up over a period of time what were common technical indicator values during that period.

So this has generated two questions for me.

For the first scenario does it matter how the data is structured. If
everything is in a one-dimensional array with say 50 labels and one.
target that is a calculation of the difference between the close
today and the close in x days. Can I just place the data in any order?  Or is it
helpful to group like data together.  For example,
if each row has five days of lookback data in it, would it be better
to group everything from five days previous together (-5 day price
change, -5RIS, -5MACD, x, x, x,), then (-4 day price change, -4RIS,
-4MACD, x, x, x,), etc, etc. or is it better for lump all five look back technical
indicators together (-5RSI, -4RSI,-3RSI, etc. etc.)
and then do the same for MACD, or whatever other indicators I have.  Does the model
care about structure arrangement.  Or is this something I just need to play with to see
what works best?
For my other question.  If I pulled a historic list of stocks, I knew that were up >5%
10 days in the future (I have about 20 years of data for the US exchanges) and I wanted
to know what the common technical indicators were at that time what would be the best
model to use for that?  While I could probably just chart that in excel if I wanted to
I am curious if there is a tensor flow model for it.


I really just need to find the time to take a course on it.   I am just trying to get somewhat more familiar with the structure first.

Probably can disregard this.  Seems like I need to spend more time on the documentations on weights.  I got some very interesting results moving around the data points
